# How to collapse all the groups of CListCtrl?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have created a CListCtrl with groups in it. I need to expand/collapse the group dynamically. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[LVM_SETGROUPINFO message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) updates list view group data, including state. And one of the [states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774769%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is:

> LVGS_COLLAPSED The group is collapsed.

Hence, you send a message and update the state. MFC wrapper over it is [`CListCtrl::SetGroupInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eza63k8z).